# How to access data from outside the instance in Vue js?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-cli

I'd like to get access to vm data from outside the instance like so:

**myComponent.vue**

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            name: 'Joe'
        };
    }
}
```

**main.js**

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    render: h => h(myComponent)
});
```

**Desired Result**

```
console.log(vm.name);   // should return - Joe
```

For some reason, console returns undefined. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: To add to the above, if I console.log(vm), it returns an object with all parameters just fine. But inside the object $data: (...) parameter doesn't have any data

Comment: `vm.name` is data of root component, not `myApp.vue` component.

Comment: so how do you get to myApp.vue component then from main.js?

Comment: Currently how do you import `myApp.vue` and use it?

Comment: in main.js: import myApp from './myApp'; and then use it in the example above

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To access vue.js object datas from inside you can use $property_name. Example

```js
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
      return {
        name: "Kapucni",
      }
    },
  template: '<div>{{ name }}</div>'
});

// use $name .property
console.log(vm.$data.name);
console.log(vm.$el);
// calling functions from $method, etc ...
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id='app'>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm... for some reason this didn't work for me either. I'm using vue-cli and webpack, maybe some behaviour is different in this environment... $data object doesn't return anything

Comment: maybe upload your minimal project with settings to codesandbox

Comment: For example from console in my Nuxt + Vue project I can access the data like `app.__vue__.$root.$data`, where `$root` is my component name

Comment: thanks for this - I'm using vue via script and lost the vue context in an axios catch block for some reason

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to comments from ittus, I realised that I have to look for child components, not the root component.

We can get to child component like so:

```
vm.$children[0].name
```

where $children[0] is a direct (and first in this case) child of the root component.

Comment: Update; In 2022, $children has been removed from Vue 3. Just in case someone still looking for a solution, visiting [Vue 3 how to get information about $children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64154002/vue-3-how-to-get-information-about-children) may help.

Answer (score 0):

Best practices are using State in Vuex for unified data storage and secure and standardized data modification and retrieval. You can read more here: https://v3.vuex.vuejs.org/#what-is-a-state-management-pattern.

If you using State in Vuex and Vue 3 you can:

store.js

```js
import 'es6-promise/auto';
import {createStore} from 'vuex'

export const store = createStore({
    state () {
        return {
            count: 1,
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        incrementCount (state) {
            state.count++
        },
        setCount (state, newValue) {
            state.count = newValue;
        },
    },
    getters: {
        getCount: state => {
            return '*' + state.count + '*';
        }
    }
})
```

app.js

```js
import {store} from "./store"; 
const app = createApp({...})
app.use(store);
export const vue_app = app.mount('#vue_app');
```

and in Javascript to modify:

```js
const store = vue_app.__vue_app__._context.provides.store; // Store instance
store._state.data.count; // get value
store.getters.getCount; // get value by the getter
store._mutations.incrementCount[0](); // modification by the mutation "incrementCount"
store._mutations.setCount[0](123); // modification by the mutation "setCount"
store._state.data.count = 123; // direct modification
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I was able to access the data using
`vm._data.name`