# Vue 3 how to get information about $children

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

This my old code with VUE 2 in Tabs component:

```
created() {
   this.tabs = this.$children;
}
```

Tabs:

```
<Tabs> 
  <Tab title="tab title">
    ....
  </Tab>
  <Tab title="tab title">
    ....
  </Tab> 
</Tabs>
```

VUE 3:
How can I get some information about childrens in Tabs component, using composition API? Get length, iterate over them, and create tabs header, ...etc? Any ideas? (using composition API)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is my Vue 3 component now. I used provide to get information in child `Tab` component.

```html
<template>
  <div class="tabs">
    <div class="tabs-header">
      <div
        v-for="(tab, index) in tabs"
        :key="index"
        @click="selectTab(index)"
        :class="{'tab-selected': index === selectedIndex}"
        class="tab"
      >
        {{ tab.props.title }}
      </div>
    </div>
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import {defineComponent, reactive, provide, onMounted, onBeforeMount, toRefs, VNode} from "vue";
    
interface TabProps {
  title: string;
}
    
export default defineComponent({
  name: "Tabs",
  setup(_, {slots}) {
    const state = reactive({
      selectedIndex: 0,
      tabs: [] as VNode<TabProps>[],
      count: 0
    });
    
    provide("TabsProvider", state);
    
    const selectTab = (i: number) => {
      state.selectedIndex = i;
    };
    
    onBeforeMount(() => {
      if (slots.default) {
        state.tabs = slots.default().filter((child) => child.type.name === "Tab");
      }
    });

    onMounted(() => {
      selectTab(0);
    });

    return {...toRefs(state), selectTab};
  }
});
</script>
```

Tab component:

```html
<script lang="ts">
export default defineComponent({
  name: "Tab",
  setup() {
    const index = ref(0);
    const isActive = ref(false);

    const tabs = inject("TabsProvider");

    watch(
      () => tabs.selectedIndex,
      () => {
        isActive.value = index.value === tabs.selectedIndex;
      }
    );

    onBeforeMount(() => {
      index.value = tabs.count;
      tabs.count++;
      isActive.value = index.value === tabs.selectedIndex;
    });
    return {index, isActive};
  }
});
</script>

<template>
  <div class="tab" v-show="isActive">
      <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: It's unclear, how do you make tab active. With $children I had component instance and could write "tab.active = true". But now tab is VNode. You store selectedIndex, but how do you use it in child tab?

Comment: Its kind of painful to see this much code to get  children elements. Are we heading at right direction in using frameworks that are so stupid

Comment: This is unreadable madness for what should be simple code. I can't believe this is acceptable frontend code design to people who are supposed to be professionals. I've seen more readable shaders.

Answer (score 15):

Oh guys, I solved it:

```
this.$slots.default().filter(child => child.type.name === 'Tab')
```

Comment: where did you get that 'slots' from?

Comment: Use `this.$slots.default()` instead

Comment: @Katinka -> In composition API setup method => setup(_, {slots})

Comment: Not sure why they deprecated the $children property :( 

This method works but requires passing any data to the slot like you do in the template

`this.$slots.default({....})`

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: this.$root.$slots.default is not a function

Answer (score 10):

My solution for scanning children elements (after much sifting through vue code) is this.

```
export function findChildren(parent, matcher) {
  const found = [];
  const root = parent.$.subTree;
  walk(root, child => {
    if (!matcher || matcher.test(child.$options.name)) {
      found.push(child);
    }
  });
  return found;
}

function walk(vnode, cb) {
  if (!vnode) return;

  if (vnode.component) {
    const proxy = vnode.component.proxy;
    if (proxy) cb(vnode.component.proxy);
    walk(vnode.component.subTree, cb);
  } else if (vnode.shapeFlag & 16) {
    const vnodes = vnode.children;
    for (let i = 0; i < vnodes.length; i++) {
      walk(vnodes[i], cb);
    }
  }
}
```

This will return the child Components.   My use for this is I have some generic dialog handling code that searches for child form element components to consult their validity state.

```
const found = findChildren(this, /^(OSelect|OInput|OInputitems)$/);
const invalid = found.filter(input => !input.checkHtml5Validity());
```

Comment: thank you so much. your walk() method solves my issue

Comment: this works, I wish there was just a getter like this built-into Vue. I don't know whether Vue changed implementation or what, but you have to replace `.name` with `.__name` for this to work as expected. I also added a depth param to restrict it.

Comment: Thank you!! This answer actually works almost the same as the $children. I tried accessing the components through the slot, but i didnt get all the props so it was kind of hard, this actually works great!!

Comment: I also used your function, and updated it a bit with an extra to find in what slot the child component is mounted in, i posted it on my gist.
https://gist.github.com/erdesigns-eu/efb8d472684cabaa3573da65b97cf9d9

Answer (score 9):

To someone wanting whole code:

Tabs.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li v-for="tab in tabs" :class="{ 'is-active': tab.isActive }">
                    <a :href="tab.href" @click="selectTab(tab)">{{ tab.name }}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="tabs-details">
            <slot></slot>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "Tabs",
        data() {
            return {tabs: [] };
        },
        created() {

        },
        methods: {
            selectTab(selectedTab) {
                this.tabs.forEach(tab => {
                    tab.isActive = (tab.name == selectedTab.name);
                });
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Tab.vue

```
<template>
    <div v-show="isActive"><slot></slot></div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "Tab",
        props: {
            name: { required: true },
            selected: { default: false}
        },

        data() {

            return {
                isActive: false
            };

        },

        computed: {

            href() {
                return '#' + this.name.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '-');
            }
        },

        mounted() {

            this.isActive = this.selected;

        },

        created() {

            this.$parent.tabs.push(this);

        },
    }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

App.js

```
<template>
    <Tabs>
                    <Tab :selected="true"
                         :name="'a'">
                        aa
                    </Tab>
                    <Tab :name="'b'">
                        bb
                    </Tab>
                    <Tab :name="'c'">
                        cc
                    </Tab>
                </Tabs>
<template/>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is is not solution for Vue 3 + composition API.
I resolve it in setup method 'setup(_, {slots})'

Answer (score 6):

If you copy pasted same code as me

then just add to the "tab" component a created method which adds itself to the tabs array of its parent

```
created() {
    
        this.$parent.tabs.push(this); 

    },
```

Comment: when having multiple components like this, this will end up in something like:

"Maximum recursive updates exceeded in component ...."

Answer (score 6):

With script setup syntax, you can use `useSlots`: https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#useslots-useattrs

```
<script setup>
import { useSlots, ref, computed } from 'vue';

const props = defineProps({
    perPage: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
});

const slots = useSlots();

const amountToShow = ref(props.perPage);
const totalChildrenCount = computed(() => slots.default()[0].children.length);
const childrenToShow = computed(() => slots.default()[0].children.slice(0, amountToShow.value));
</script>

<template>
    <component
        :is="child"
        v-for="(child, index) in childrenToShow"
        :key="`show-more-${child.key}-${index}`"
    ></component>
</template>
```

Comment: Your's is the best answer here. I don't have to write any weird looking JS, and it's simple as hell. Thanks! And by the way, how did you know about `slots.default()`? I checked the docs but didn't find any mention of it.

Comment: @PraiseDare thanks, I knew about slots default because its fundamental to how the slots work. there is always a default slot that you get from `<slot></slot>` and any other slot must be named. Besides that I think my example assumes the default slot is a list of children, like `<slot v-for="child in children">`. You are likely correct to observe it may not work for named slots.

Comment: Actually that sounds a bit weird. I'm not sure. It's worth experimenting to see how the children can be read from the parent. You can console.log the value of `useSlots()` and see what's in there.

Answer (score 2):

I made a small improvement to Ingrid Oberbüchler's component as it was not working with hot-reload/dynamic tabs.

in Tab.vue:

```
onBeforeMount(() => {
  // ...
})
onBeforeUnmount(() => {
  tabs.count--
})
```

In Tabs.vue:

```
const selectTab = // ...
// ...
watch(
  () => state.count,
  () => {
    if (slots.default) {
      state.tabs = slots.default().filter((child) => child.type.name === "Tab")
    }
  }
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I found this updated Vue3 tutorial [Building a Reusable Tabs Component with Vue Slots](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ROGeJxI2L58) very helpful with explanations that connected with me.

It uses ref, provide and inject to replace `this.tabs = this.$children;` with which I was having the same problem.

I had been following the earlier version of the tutorial for building a tabs component (Vue2) that I originally found [Creating Your Own Reusable Vue Tabs Component](https://learnvue.co/2019/12/building-reusable-components-in-vuejs-tabs/).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and after doing so much research and asking myself why they had removed `$children`, I discovered that they created a better and more elegant alternative.

It's about Dynamic Components. (`<component: is =" currentTabComponent "> </component>`).

The information I found here:

https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-basics.html#dynamic-components

I hope this is useful for you, greetings to all !!

Comment: Dynamic components were already available years ago in Vue 2. Not sure what they have to do with accessing children

Comment: True, what happened to me was that I did it before as it appears in the link that I am going to share and it gave me the same problem as everyone else here: https://learnvue.co/2019/12/building-reusable-components -in-vuejs-tabs/

Answer (score 0):

In 3.x, the $children property is removed and no longer supported. Instead, if you need to access a child component instance, they recommend using $refs. as a array

https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/children.html#_2-x-syntax

Answer (score 0):

A per [Vue documentation](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#useslots-and-useattrs), supposing you have a default slot under `Tabs` component, you could have access to the slot´s children directly in the template like so:

```
// Tabs component

<template>
  <div v-if="$slots && $slots.default && $slots.default()[0]" class="tabs-container">
    <button
      v-for="(tab, index) in getTabs($slots.default()[0].children)"
      :key="index"
      :class="{ active: modelValue === index }"
      @click="$emit('update:model-value', index)"
    >
      <span>
        {{ tab.props.title }}
      </span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <slot></slot>
</template>

<script setup>
  defineProps({ modelValue: Number })

  defineEmits(['update:model-value'])

  const getTabs = tabs => {
    if (Array.isArray(tabs)) {
      return tabs.filter(tab => tab.type.name === 'Tab')
    } else {
      return []
    }
</script>

<style>
...
</style>
```

And the `Tab` component could be something like:

```
// Tab component

<template>
  <div v-show="active">
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default { name: 'Tab' }
</script>

<script setup>
  defineProps({
    active: Boolean,
    title: String
  })
</script>
```

The implementation should look similar to the following (considering an array of objects, one for each section, with a `title` and a `component`):

```
...
<tabs v-model="active">
  <tab
    v-for="(section, index) in sections"
    :key="index"
    :title="section.title"
    :active="index === active"
  >
    <component
      :is="section.component"
    ></component>
  </app-tab>
</app-tabs>
...
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const active = ref(0)
</script>
```

Another way is to make use of `useSlots` as explained in Vue´s documentation (link above).

Answer (score 0):

In 3.x version, the `$children` is removed and no longer supported. Using ref to access children instance.

```
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'
import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent .vue'

const child = ref(null)

onMounted(() => {
   console.log(child.value) // log an instance of <Child />
})
</script>

<template>
  <ChildComponent ref="child" />
</template>
```

Detail: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#template-refs

Answer (score -1):

Based on the answer of @Urkle:

```
/**
 * walks a node down
 * @param vnode
 * @param cb
 */
export function walk(vnode, cb) {
    if (!vnode) return;

    if (vnode.component) {
        const proxy = vnode.component.proxy;
        if (proxy) cb(vnode.component.proxy);
        walk(vnode.component.subTree, cb);
    } else if (vnode.shapeFlag & 16) {
        const vnodes = vnode.children;
        for (let i = 0; i < vnodes.length; i++) {
            walk(vnodes[i], cb);
        }
    }
}
```

In **addition** to the accepted answer:

Instead of

```
this.$root.$children.forEach(component => {})
```

write

```
walk(this.$root, component => {})
```

And this is how i got it working for me.

Comment: What's the point of copy/pasting Urkle's answer?

Comment: @TristanCHARBONNIER i added "Instead of .." and "write"
I improved my writings, after your complain. thanks.