# How to access $children in Vue 3 for creating a Tabs component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I'm trying to create a `Tabs` component in **Vue 3** similar to this [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64154002/vue-3-how-to-get-information-about-children).

```html
<tabs>
   <tab title="one">content</tab>
   <tab title="two" v-if="show">content</tab> <!-- this fails -->
   <tab :title="t" v-for="t in ['three', 'four']">{{t}}</tab> <!-- also fails -->
   <tab title="five">content</tab>
</tabs>
```

Unfortunately the proposed solution does not work when the `Tab`s inside are dynamic, i.e. if there is a v-if on the `Tab` or when the `Tab`s are rendered using a `v-for` loop - it fails.

I've created a Codesandbox for it here because it contains `.vue` files:

**https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-mountain-wg0bi?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue**

[image]

I've tried using `onBeforeUpdate` like `onBeforeMount`, but that does not work either. Actually, it does insert new tabs, but *the order of tabs is changed.*

**The biggest hurdle seems to be that there seems to be no way to get/set `child` data from parent in Vue 3.** (like `$children` in Vue 2.x). Someone suggested to use `this.$.subtree.children` but then it was strongly advised against (and didn't help me anyway I tried).

Can anyone tell me how to make the `Tab` inside `Tabs` reactive and update on `v-if`, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution was [posted by @anteriovieira](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-access-children-in-vue-3-for-creating-a-tabs-component/108955) in Vuejs forum and looks like the correct way to do it. The missing piece of puzzle was `getCurrentInstance` available during `setup`

The full working code can be found here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-3-tabs-ob1it

I'm adding it here for reference of anyone coming here from Google looking for the same.

Comment: The Vuejs forum link doesn't work and the codesandbox.io link points to code that doesn't function.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a problem with using the item index as the `v-for` loop's `key`.

The first issue is you've applied `v-for`'s `key` on a child element when it should be on the parent (on the `<li>` in this case).

```html
<li v-for="(tab, i) in tabs">
  <a :key="i"> ❌
  </a>
</li>
```

Also, if the `v-for` backing array can have its items rearranged (or middle items removed), don't use the item index as the `key` because the index wouldn't provide a consistently unique value. For instance, if item 2 of 3 were removed from the list, the third item would be shifted up into index 1, taking on the `key` that was previously used by the removed item. Since no `key`s in the list have changed, Vue reuses the existing virtual DOM nodes as an optimization, and no rerendering occurs.

A good `key` to select in your case is the tab's `title` value, as that is always unique per tab in your example. Here's your new `Tab.vue` with the `index` replaced with a `title` prop:

```js
// Tab.vue
export default {
  props: ["title"], 
  setup(props) {
    const isActive = ref(false)
    const tabs = inject("TabsProvider")

    watch(
      () => tabs.selectedIndex,
      () => {
        isActive.value = props.title === tabs.selectedIndex
      }                        
    )

    onBeforeMount(() => {
      isActive.value = props.title === tabs.selectedIndex
    })                       

    return { isActive }
  },
}
```

Then, update your `Tabs.vue` template to use the tab's `title` instead of `i`:

```html
<li class="nav-item" v-for="tab in tabs" :key="tab.props.title">
  <a                                                     
    @click.prevent="selectedIndex = tab.props.title"
    class="nav-link"                          
    :class="tab.props.title === selectedIndex && 'active'"
    href="#"          
  >
    {{ tab.props.title }}
  </a>
</li>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/rendering-tabs-in-vue-3-xif9p?file=/src/components/Tabs.vue)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I understand the keying much better now. But in your demo it still does not render the `v-for` tabs: see the `<tab :title="t.title" v-for="t in more" :key="t">Dynamic {{ t }}</tab>` in App.vue. Any ideas?

Comment: Also one more comment. in Vue 2 it wasn't required to "key" the tabs with `title` or anything because `$children` provided direct access to slot children. So it was perfectly fine to do `<Tabs><Tab>1</Tab><Tab>2</Tab></Tabs>`. Now it seems that we need to specify a `title` or some sort of key on each `<Tab>`. Can you think of a way to identify the selectedTab without a tab.title or any other key?

Comment: @supersan I fixed the issue regarding the missing dynamic tabs (see updated demo), but this solution (and the original one you linked to) is not ideal IMO because it requires reaching into `VNode` internals to parse the Tab's titles just to show the tab headers. I think a better solution would be to pass the data as a prop on `Tabs` and/or using scoped slots.

Comment: Also, consider using an existing tab component, or a library that provides one (e.g., Vuetify, BootstrapVue, Buefy, etc.).

Comment: Thanks so much for your help again. You're right this Vnode thing sucks. Things were much simpler in Vue 2.x as we had direct access to slot's `$children` plus it was also reactive, so even if the tabs were dragged or sorted it would update automatically. I did look into Bootstrapvue, Vuetify, etc but those haven't migrated to Vue 3 just (who knows they are facing the same issues lol). Anyway so I'm sticking with Vue 2.x for now. It is more than enough for my needs anyway. I was only temped to upgrade because of `vite` which looks like a huge timesaver.

Comment: Sir, I am using what you wrote, but selectTab 0 is not active, how can we activate it?

Answer (score 0):

Since access to slots is available as `$slots` in the template (see [Vue documentation](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#useslots-and-useattrs)), you could also do the following:

```
// Tabs component

<template>
  <div v-if="$slots && $slots.default && $slots.default()[0]" class="tabs-container">
    <button
      v-for="(tab, index) in getTabs($slots.default()[0].children)"
      :key="index"
      :class="{ active: modelValue === index }"
      @click="$emit('update:model-value', index)"
    >
      <span>
        {{ tab.props.title }}
      </span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <slot></slot>
</template>

<script setup>
  defineProps({ modelValue: Number })

  defineEmits(['update:model-value'])

  const getTabs = tabs => {
    if (Array.isArray(tabs)) {
      return tabs.filter(tab => tab.type.name === 'Tab')
    } else {
      return []
    }
</script>

<style>
...
</style>
```

And the `Tab` component could be something like:

```
// Tab component

<template>
  <div v-show="active">
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default { name: 'Tab' }
</script>

<script setup>
  defineProps({
    active: Boolean,
    title: String
  })
</script>
```

The implementation should look similar to the following (considering an array of objects, one for each section, with a `title` and a `component`):

```
...
<tabs v-model="active">
  <tab
    v-for="(section, index) in sections"
    :key="index"
    :title="section.title"
    :active="index === active"
  >
    <component
      :is="section.component"
    ></component>
  </app-tab>
</app-tabs>
...
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const active = ref(0)
</script>
```